# Multiple conditions checking to avoid duplicates in twoSum solution

Tags: python, python-3.x

I device three solutions to twoSum problems

> Given all arrays of integers, return **indices** of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have **exactly** one solution, and you may not use the *same* element twice.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,
>
> Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
> return [0, 1].
> ```

One is manipulate data structure

```
class Solution1(): #Manipulate Data 
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        nums_d = {}
        couples = []
        #O(n)
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            nums_d.setdefault(nums[i], []).append(i)

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            complement = target - nums[i]
            nums_d[nums[i]].pop(0) #remove the fixer
            result = nums_d.get(complement)#hash table to search 
            #if j is not Nne and j is not empty.
            if result: #if exits, it should be [j] 
                couples.append([nums[i], complement])
        return couples
```

Second is multiple conditions checking

```
class Solution2: #Double Pass Approach 
    def twoSum(self, nums, target) -> List[List[int]]:
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        """
        if len(nums) < 2:
            return []

        couples = []
        nums_d:dict = {}
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            #nums_d.setdefault(nums[i], []).append(i)
            nums_d[nums[i]] = i 

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            complement = target - nums[i]
            # nums_d[nums[i]].pop(0) #remove the fixer 
            if nums_d.get(complement) != None and nums_d.get(complement) != i: 
                couples.append([nums[i], complement])
        return couples
```

Third only operate the indexes

```
class Solution: 3#Single Pass Approach 
    def twoSum(self, nums, target) -> List[List[int]]:
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        """
        nums_d:dict = {}
        couples = []

        if len(nums) < 2:
            return []

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            complement = target - nums[i]
            logging.debug(f"complement: {complement}")
            logging.debug(f"Check: {nums_d.get(complement)}")

            if nums_d.get(complement) != None:
                # couples.append([i, nums_d.get(complement)])    
                couples.append([nums[i], complement])          
            nums_d[nums[i]] = i 

            logging.debug(f"nums_d: {nums_d}")
        return couples
```

and my testing case

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    # logging.debug("Class TestCase started.")
    """
    Test for 'twoSum.py'
    """
    def setUp(self):
        self.solution = Solution1()
        self.solution2 = Solution2()
        self.solution3 = Solution3()

    def test_two_sum3(self):
        #random is present
        target = 30
        nums = random.sample(range(20), k=20)
        print(f"\ntarget: {target} \nnums: {nums}")
        #Input no-replacement nums
        print('Solution Length:', len(self.solution.twoSum(nums, target)))
        print('result:', self.solution.twoSum(nums, target))
        print('Solution2 Length:', len(self.solution2.twoSum(nums, target)))
        print('result2:', self.solution2.twoSum(nums, target))
        print('Solution3 Length:', len(self.solution3.twoSum(nums, target)))
        print('result3:', self.solution3.twoSum(nums, target))


unittest.main()
```

Get the result

```
nums: [8, 0, 2, 15, 18, 5, 4, 14, 3, 12, 17, 19, 11, 10, 6, 16, 7, 13, 1, 9]
Solution Length: 4
result: [[18, 12], [14, 16], [17, 13], [19, 11]]
Solution2 Length: 8
result2: [[18, 12], [14, 16], [12, 18], [17, 13], [19, 11], [11, 19], [16, 14], [13, 17]]
Solution3 Length: 4
result3: [[12, 18], [11, 19], [16, 14], [13, 17]]
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s
```

I am fan of solution2.

How to rewrite `if nums_d.get(complement) != None and nums_d.get(complement) != i:`
to avoid duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I want to say, your solutions are not exactly matched the two sum problem statement.

> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

So actually, you don't need record multiple results, just find and return it.

According to your solution and testcase, here I assume your scenario is applied to the data which have mutilple results and ignore duplicate pairs.

I figure out two ways to improve your `Solution2`, also I optimize your code, you can compare and learn from comment:

1. Use `set` and `sorted pair` to remove duplicates:

```
class Solution4:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target) -> List[List[int]]:
        if len(nums) < 2:
            return []

        couples = set()
        nums_d = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(nums)}     # init by dict comprehension

        for i, v in enumerate(nums):    # enumerate is better here
            complement = target - v
            if nums_d.get(complement, i) != i:      # use sentinel, more concise
            # if complement in nums_d and nums_d[complement] != i:  # more understandable
                couples.add(tuple(sorted((nums[i], complement))))   # need immutable in set
        return list(map(list, couples))     # convert back to list
```

2. Only add pairs which `complement >= v`(sorted pair), more efficient than above.

*Attention: this solution will not pass the case like [15, 15] in input, I just assume no edge cases like that, <strike>because all of your 3 original solutions will not pass, either.</strike>*

```
class Solution5:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target) -> List[List[int]]:
        if len(nums) < 2:
            return []

        couples = []
        nums_d = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(nums)}     # init by dict comprehension

        for i, v in enumerate(nums):    # enumerate is better here
            complement = target - v
            if complement >= v:
                if nums_d.get(complement, i) != i:      # use sentinel, more concise
                # if complement in nums_d and nums_d[complement] != i:  # more understandable
                    couples.append([v, complement])
        return couples
```

By the way, I'm the fan of `Solution3`, it update index while traversal, it is a common technique, use less extra space and one pass.

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )